# SAPUI5 Page footer is not propertly shown using sap.tnt.ToolPage on iOS devices

Tags: ios, footer, sapui5

OpenUI5 version: 1.40 - 1.44.3 (last beta until now)

Browser/version (+device/version): Safari/Chrome on iOS iPhone iPads

Any other tested browsers/devices(OK/FAIL):
on PC/MAC/Android devices - OK
Safari/Chrome on iOS iPhone iPads - FAIL

EXAMPLE URL: www.sudchiamanord.com/demo

SOURCE CODE: www.sudchiamanord.com/demo/WebContent.zip

I have made an application using sap.m.ToolPage as main container using Component.js and manifest.js files.
In the mainContent aggregation I've inserted a sap.m.App in order to use the routing mechanism that works with the "pages" aggregation .

If I load a page with a footer, this footer will be displayed under the bottom limit of the pages only on iOS devices, so it's not will be shown.

If the "header" of sap.tnt.ToolPage is empty, the footers will be shown correctly also in the iOS devices.

[IMG: Safari on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr5Hg.jpg)

[IMG: Chrome on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsDpz.jpg)